# What features are impossible to develop when developing a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

Is there anything that can be built using "code" but can't be built using Wordpress or no-code platforms?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** No coding? Yes

**Detailed answer:**
WordPress is a [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system), the [Hook Based structure](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/) of WordPress allows you to use different plugins and themes. You can manage almost all input data, processing process and output information. **But** here's the thing:

> **Using too many plugins can reduce performance, reduce security, reduce stability, and make management difficult. If you use plugins
> for anything, every WordPress update and plugins will bring you to
> tears :)**

WordPress is very powerful, this power is not because of plugins or themes, but because **developer friendly** WordPress has had a great impact on its popularity. Almost anything you can do with PHP, JS, React JS, etc. can be done with WordPress. WordPress has a powerful [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) and allows developers to use it to code any language and for any device.

WordPress has been trying to become the largest [Headless CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_content_management_system) in the world for the last few years. The [Gutenberg](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/) project was implemented in this direction with **REACT JS** and is developing rapidly.

WordPress is becoming more and more inclined towards JS, so without programming knowledge, you will definitely have a lot of problems in the future.

Finally, the less plugins and themes you depend on, the better WordPress works. Many large companies such as [Microsoft](https://blogs.microsoft.com/), [Facebook](https://about.fb.com/news/), [Mozilla Foundation](https://blog.mozilla.org/), [Harvard](http://blogs.harvard.edu/) University and [MIT](https://sloanreview.mit.edu/), [White house](https://www.whitehouse.gov/), [etc](https://wordpress.org/showcase/). currently use WordPress, but not with dozens of plugins :)

WordPress is scalable and has the ability to integrate with scalable technologies such as [K8S](https://github.com/IBM/Scalable-WordPress-deployment-on-Kubernetes), ElasticSearch, GraphQL, etc.

WordPress's market share [shows](https://www.datanyze.com/market-share/wcms--7/wordpress-market-share) that there are websites in the world below 100 Alexa rank that are managed with WordPress. If you want to use WordPress on a large scale, you have to code.